# SCPSolver with Java nullPointerException. A runnable example

Tags: java, linear-programming, scpsolver

I am trying to use some linear programming tools with Java. I decided to explore SCPSolver because it comes with a documentation.

So I tried to run the example as shown in SCPSolver home page: [the low lever interface example](http://scpsolver.org/)

```
public class SCPSolverDemo {
  public static void main(String ag[]){
    LinearProgram lp = new LinearProgram(new double[]{5.0,10.0}); 
    lp.addConstraint(new LinearBiggerThanEqualsConstraint(new double[]{3.0,1.0}, 8.0, "c1")); 
    lp.addConstraint(new LinearBiggerThanEqualsConstraint(new double[]{0.0,4.0}, 4.0, "c2")); 
    lp.addConstraint(new LinearSmallerThanEqualsConstraint(new double[]{2.0,0.0}, 2.0, "c3")); 
    lp.setMinProblem(true); 
    LinearProgramSolver solver  = SolverFactory.newDefault();
    double[] sol = solver.solve(lp);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sol)); //line 23
  }
}
```

When I run it, i get an error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at drafts.SCPSolverDemo.main(SCPSolverDemo.java:23)
```

I realized that `SolverFactory.newDefault();` retruns null. Documentation sais that

*Searches for service provider of the LinearProgramSolver service and returns the first instance it found. If no service was found, it prints the stack trace to stderr and returns null. When this method is first invoked, it initializes the ServiceLoader, which locates available services from the classpath. Subsequent calls use the result of this first initialization. Therefore, if there are no available services at the moment of the first call, there will be no available services for the rest of the program run. Future implementations might ignore this problem.*

but I don't know what to do to fix the problem. In this point, I would like your help. I cannot understand much from the existing example and I don't know what to do.

Could somebody please give me a runnable example, in order to understand what is going on? Thank you in advance

Comment: what's the package (import) of SolverFactory?

Comment: import scpsolver.lpsolver.SolverFactory;

Comment: Do you want me to add all other imports?

Comment: Do you see any exception on console? I am sure there will be some? Native library not loaded or something?

Comment: no, I see nothing. Only this exception

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I get the same one.

Comment: Yes, I solved it. Should I answer it to my question or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed multiple JDKs on your system. On IntelliJ make sure you have the correct SDK selected for x86 JDK version. Its easier to keep track if you name your SDKs in the 'Platform Settings'-> SDK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, you need to install de JDK7 x86 and then it works. Tested on IntelliJ with jdk-7u79-windows-i586.

Comment: I did install JDK7 but I get the same exception